# How to use semantic-release for .toml based projects

Tags: python, toml, semantic-release

I've created a package hosted in gitlab. I want to use semantic-release for python versioning, but issues arise when gitlab's ci runs on a detached head. How can I configure semantic-release to update once the changes have merged and push the results to HEAD? I've pretty much only found some support for npm/node, but nothing for a python/.toml based package.

I tried putting in semantic-release as a gitlab command.